# Access a Component Method of Vue from a Service Typescript

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am new to vue. I have a vue component that has a method.

**ComponentFile.vue**

```
async search() {
  // Retrieve some data
}
```

I need to call this method from a service typescript file.

**ServiceFile.ts**

```
async processFile() {
  model.name = 'Steve'
  model.age = 21
  // Call the search method of the component file.
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

The other way I was trying is to use a watcher at the component and trigger that through the service file, but I don't know how to do that?

**ComponentFile.vue**

```
const Props = Vue.extend({
  props: {    
    loadValues: Number
  },
});    
.........
.........    
@Watch("loadValues")
async search() {
      // Retrieve some data
    }
```

**ServiceFile.ts**

```
async processFile() {
  model.name = 'Steve'
  model.age = 21
  // loadValues++ - to trigger the component method.
}
```

My colleague suggested using vuex store might be an option. But I am not sure how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write function in TS file and import it in TS service and Vue component like this:

```
<script>
import { search } from 'search';

export default {
   name: 'ComponentFile',
   methods: {
    search
   },
 };
</script>
```